# In ES6 JavaScript, we can use `let` in a for-loop but not in a while-loop?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

The following works:

```js
let re = /\d/g;

while (result = re.exec("654 321")) console.log(result);
```

However, if we follow the way how a for-loop is written:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) console.log(i);
```

```js
for (const a of [1,3,5]) console.log(a);
```

and use (with the expected result of an error):

```js
let re = /\d/g;

while (let result = re.exec("654 321")) console.log(result);
```

then the `let` will break the code.  What rule in ES6 governs that we cannot use `let` in this case? While usually, we declare a variable before the while statement, in this case, it makes sense not to. It might appear using a `let` or even `const` can make sense?

Comment: This has nothing to do with ES6, `while` never allowed statements, only expressions.

Comment: You could do `let result; while (result = ...`

Comment: The while statement creates a loop that executes a specified statement as long as the test condition evaluates to true. The condition is evaluated before executing the statement, so having a statement in while is not right syntactically

Comment: so this is not a valid question? What merits it to get downvotes as if this is an invalid coding question?

Comment: @ASDFGerte in some languages, statements or expressions are not so different, and actually, even in JS, they seem not so different... when we say `console.log()` it returns a value, so in a way it is both a statement and an expression

Comment: Yeah, it's sometimes a mysterious thing why some questions that look okay, would attract downvotes for no clear reason.  Maybe it becomes a compulsary habbit to some users, who knows. Or they see the question, get the feeling that's it wasted a few seconds of their free time.  It doesn't help then that one doesn't get a -1 reputation penalty for downvoting a question.  But I think your question is valid enough.

Comment: *"when we say `console.log()` it returns a value, so in a way it is both a statement and an expression"* Placed on it's own line that would be an [*ExpressionStatement*](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/#sec-expression-statement). Basically when you place an expression where a statement is expected, the engine will parse this as an expression statement. Syntactically it's still well-defined what an expression and what a statement is.

Answer (score 3):

It's because everything inside the braces in your while-Statement is a condition.
You **cannot** define new variables inside a condition.

You can use let inside the for loop, because of the structure:

```
for (<declare variable>;<condition>;<iterator>)
```

Comment: *"You cannot define new variables inside a condition."* That's not quite true. In non-strict mode `while (foo = 42) {}` works even if `foo` hasn't been declared yet.

Comment: Yes, but it's considered **very** bad practise. Additionally it's not allowed in most other languages, so it wouldn't be a wise decision to get into the habit of doing it like this.

Comment: Of course. I'm just playing devils advocate and  challenge refute your explanation. It's really about the fact that the "parameter" of a `while` loop has to be an expression. Saying "you cannot define new variables" isn't really an explanation IMO, because the OP already found that out through trying.

Answer (score 1):

> The while statement creates a loop that executes a specified statement
>   as long as the test condition evaluates to true. The condition is
>   evaluated before executing the statement:
>
> ```
> while (condition)
>   statement
> ```
>
> **condition** An expression evaluated before each pass through the loop. If this condition evaluates to true, statement is executed. When
>   condition evaluates to false, execution continues with the statement
>   after the while loop.
>
> **statement** An optional statement that is executed as long as the condition evaluates to true. To execute multiple statements within the
>   loop, use a block statement `({ ... })`to group those statements.

So having a **statement** in while in-place of a condition expression is not right syntactically. Please [see this for more details](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/while).

Answer (score 0):

the code snippet doesn't run for me. (edit: tried it again and it threw an error).
but anyway it seems wrong:
the initial statement of a `for` loop is executed only once. which means it defines `i` only once.
but in the case of a `while` you are defining `result` again and again. Which is probably why it isn't allowed and throws an error

Comment: "the code snippet doesn't run for me." the last snippet? That's the whole point of the question

Comment: No. I meant it didn't run like the JS syntax was incorrect.

Comment: Which, again, was the point.

Answer (score -2):

The `let` returns undefined, while the assignment to an undefined variable will return the value.

```js
let a = 3;
// undefined;
b = 4;
// 4;
```

So your while loop will never run.