# Iterate over RegExp.exec(...)

Tags: javascript

From the [`RegExp.exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) page on MDN, it gives the following example of iterating through a match with the `g` flag set:

```js
const regex1 = RegExp('foo*', 'g');
const str1 = 'table football, foosball';
let array1;

while ((array1 = regex1.exec(str1)) !== null) {
  console.log(`Found ${array1[0]}. Next starts at ${regex1.lastIndex}.`);
  // expected output: "Found foo. Next starts at 9."
  // expected output: "Found foo. Next starts at 19."
}
```

I have two questions about this code. The first one is why the `!=== null` is used here, why wouldn't the `while` loop be properly coded as:

```
while (array1 = regex1.exec(str1)) { // implicitly casts to boolean?
  console.log(`...`);

}
```

The above seems much more readable to me, but was wondering why the MDN docs used the first approach? Second, is it possible to declare and define the variable directly in the `while` loop? Something like:

```
while (let array1 = regex1.exec(str1)) { // don't need the `let array1` above?
  console.log(`...`);

}
```

Or is that not supported in the JS language?

Comment: "*// implicitly casts to boolean?*" essentially yes. Some values are [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy). "*was wondering why the MDN docs used the first approach?*" why not? It's not wrong. It's also more explicit. I am not sure there is a deeper meaning here than maybe being slightly clearer. "*Or is that not supported in the JS language?*" [it's not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59952522/in-es6-javascript-we-can-use-let-in-a-for-loop-but-not-in-a-while-loop).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why the `!== null` is used here...?

True, in this case it is not needed. `.exec()` returns either an array or `null`, and since arrays are always truthy there is no need to explicitly compare with `null`.

> Is it possible to declare and define the variable directly in the while loop?

No. If you want that, then turn to the `for` loop, which *does* support this:

```
for (let array1; array1 = regex1.exec(str1); null) {
  console.log(`...`);
}
```

This does indeed have the advantage that `array1` has a more restricted scope. NB: I provided `null` to stress that the third part of the `for` header is intentionally unused.

Comment: thanks. If you were writing the code, which approach would you use? A `while` loop? A `for` loop? And with or without the separate-line `let array1` declaration?

Comment: That is a matter of opinion, although it is good practice to make the scope of variables as small as possible. Nowadays I prefer to avoid `.exec()` and work with `.matchAll()` instead.

Comment: I see, thanks for the feedback. Why do you prefer `matchAll` over `exec` ?

Comment: I prefer it because I find the mutations that happen on the regex object -- on which `.exec()` is executed -- a messy side effect.